# Error: The element type "apex:pageBlock" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</apex:pageBlock>"

Tags: visualforce, error

I am receiving this error:

- Error: lightningAccountLayout line 14, column 4: The element type "apex:pageBlock" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</apex:pageBlock>"

I'm having difficulty creating sections within a pageBlock. Is someone able to assist?

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">

  <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.styleforAccountLightningPage}"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
  
 <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(Account.Systems_Pick__c,"Medication Dispenser"), "true", "false")}"
     title="Medication Dispenser">
     
     <apex:pageblockSection>
      "Medication Dispenser Device Number: " {!$Account.MED_Device_Number__c}
     </apex:pageblockSection>
     
 </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: It looks like all of my tags match up, and I don't get an error if I remove the pageblockSection portion, but I cannot add a pageblockSection unless I am inside a pageBlock.

Comment: Looks like problem with rendered condition, it accepts true or false boolean values and not string , so this can be changed from `rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(Account.Systems_Pick__c,"Medication Dispenser"), "true", "false")}"` to `rendered="{!CONTAINS(Account.Systems_Pick__c,"Medication Dispenser")}"`

Answer (score 0):

I moved title="Medication Dispenser" before the 'rendered' section, and it seems too be working now!